# VBS writing to open file

Tags: vbscript

I have a word document that the user can input data. I have a button that will run VB to gather information. I am having trouble getting VB to write the output of the script to the document while it is open. Can VBS write to an open/active word document? Sorry if this seems basic....new to VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the method - **[getObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/getobject-function)** to set the reference to an already opened Word document as shown in the following code:

```
Dim word, docs, docName, reqdDoc
Set word = getObject(,"word.application")
Set docs = word.documents
docName = "Document1"                    'Enter the name of the document in which you want to write the data
'MsgBox docs.count
For Each doc In docs
    If StrComp(doc.fullName,docName,1)=0 Then
        Set reqdDoc = doc
        Exit For
    End If
Next
reqdDoc.Activate
word.selection.typeText "Hello There:"
```